# if one user login send message creating one message at a time 2 users login send a message create 2 messages

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, chat, real-time

how to avoid dulpicate message creatinhg 2 users login at a one time

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
def connect(self):
print("here")
self.room_name = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["room_name"]
self.room_group_name = f"chat_{self.room_name}"
query_string = self.scope['query_string'].decode('utf-8')
query_params = parse_qs(query_string)
if 'user_id' in query_params:
user_id = query_params['user_id'][0]
print("userid.......................................................................................", user_id)
user = self.authenticate_user(user_id)
if user.is_authenticated:
print("sucess authentication....................")

```
            # Join room group
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
                self.room_group_name, self.channel_name
            )

            self.accept()

def disconnect(self, close_code):
    # Leave room group
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
        self.room_group_name, self.channel_name
    )

def authenticate_user(self, user_id):
    def sync_authenticate_user():
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
            self.scope['user'] = user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            self.scope['user'] = AnonymousUser()

    thread = threading.Thread(target=sync_authenticate_user)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
    return self.scope['user']


def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
    # parse the json data into dictionary object
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)

    if text_data_json.get('action') == 'get_chat_history':

        conversation = Conversation.objects.get(id=int(self.room_name))
        all_messages = Message.objects.filter(
            conversation_id=conversation).order_by('timestamp')
        serializer = MessageSerializer(instance=all_messages, many=True)
        message_list = serializer.data


        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'type': 'message_list',
            'messages': message_list
        }))
    else:
    
        chat_type = 'chat_message'
        return_dict = {
            'type': chat_type,
            'message': text_data_json.get('message'),
            'attachment': text_data_json.get('attachment')
        }
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            return_dict
        )

def chat_message(self, event):
    print("event.............................................................................................", event)
    text_data_json = event.copy()
    text_data_json.pop("type")
    message = event.get("message", None)
    attachment = event.get("attachment", None)
    print(message, attachment,
          "........................................................................")
    conversation = Conversation.objects.get(id=int(self.room_name))

    sender = self.scope['user']
    sender_id = sender.id
    print("username is...............................................................", sender)
    print("user is...................", sender_id)
    print(conversation.id,"converstaionid")

    sender_id = self.scope['user'].id
    message = event.get("message", None)
    attachment = event.get("attachment", None)

    conversation = Conversation.objects.get(id=int(self.room_name))
    
    if attachment:
        file_str, file_ext = attachment["data"], attachment["format"]
        file_data = ContentFile(
            base64.b64decode(file_str), name=f"{secrets.token_hex(8)}.{file_ext}"
        )
        Response_ = {
            'sender': sender_id,
            'text': message,
            'conversation_id': conversation.id,
            'attachment': attachment
        }
    else:
        Response_ = {
            'sender': sender_id,
            'text': message,
            'conversation_id': conversation.id,
        }

    self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'type': 'new_message',
        'messages': Response_
    }))

    self.create_chat_message(sender_id, message, conversation, attachment)




def create_chat_message(self, sender_id, message, conversation, attachment):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            user = User.objects.select_for_update().get(id=sender_id)
            sender = Employees.objects.select_for_update().get(user=user)

            if attachment:
                existing_message = Message.objects.get(
                    sender=sender,
                    attachment=attachment,
                    text=message,
                    conversation_id=conversation
                )
                return existing_message
            else:
                new_message = Message.objects.create(
                    sender=sender,
                    text=message,
                    conversation_id=conversation
                )
                return new_message

    except (User.DoesNotExist, Employees.DoesNotExist):
        return None
```